# how do i fix this error in my text based gme

Tags: python

error

```
  File "c:\Users\o\Desktop\Main\tictactoe.py", line 14, in <module>
    place[i] = "X"
    ~~~~~^^^
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

code

```
import os
import time
board = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
# nine spaces for the tic tac toe board

place = (' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ')

print(len(board))
while True:
    os.system('cls')

    for i in range(8):
        if board[i] == 1:
         place[i] = "X"

    i = 0

    print(" ", place[0] , " ", place[1], " ", place[2], "\n", " ", place[4], " ", place[4], " ", place[5], "\n", " ", place[6], " ", place[7], " ", place[8])
`
```

Comment: `place = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']`

Comment: `place` is a tuple since it uses `(...)` instead of `[...]`. You cannot update values in tuples so `place[I] = "X"` is illegal. Make `place` a list instead of a tuple and it should work.

Comment: Tuples are immutable. Use a list. You could have found the solution to this problem with minimal research effort and I think that's why this question gets downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a list, not a Tuple:**

Tuples are immutable, meaning that they can't be changed. Tuples are created using the `tuple = (itema, itemb, ...)`, which is how you defined your `place` variable. Change that to the list syntax: `lst = [itema, itemb, ...]`

```
import os
import time
board = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
# nine spaces for the tic tac toe board

place = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']  # List not tuple!

print(len(board))
while True:
    os.system('cls')

    for i in range(8):
        if board[i] == 1:
         place[i] = "X"

    i = 0

    print(" ", place[0] , " ", place[1], " ", place[2], "\n", " ", place[4], " ", place[4], " ", place[5], "\n", " ", place[6], " ", place[7], " ", place[8])
```

For more on Tuples see:  https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp